# Como selecionar menor registro por campo

Tags: sql, mysqli

Como posso apresentar o menor fator por ID_ACORDO?

```
SELECT  LIGACOES.ID 
        ,ACORDO.ID_ACORDO
        ,ACORDO.DATA as 'DATA_ACORDO'
        ,LIGACOES.time_of_contact AS 'DATA_LIGACAO'
        ,ACORDO.data-LIGACOES.time_of_contact as FATOR

FROM SISCOB_acordo_itau_pf_varejo AS ACORDO

INNER JOIN
DWH_Developer.ASPECT_CONTACT_EVENTS AS LIGACOES ON (LIGACOES.account_number = ACORDO.id_contr)

where ACORDO.DATA>= LIGACOES.time_of_contact
```

Comment: Você quer pegar o registro que tenha o valor menor no campo ID_ACORDO, seria isto?

Comment: Não, na verdade gostaria dos registros que contém o menor fator por acordo.

Answer (score 1):

Creio ser isto , *min com Group by*

```
    SELECT  LIGACOES.ID 
        ,ACORDO.ID_ACORDO
        ,ACORDO.DATA as 'DATA_ACORDO'
        ,LIGACOES.time_of_contact AS 'DATA_LIGACAO'
        ,MIN(ACORDO.data-LIGACOES.time_of_contact) as FATOR

FROM SISCOB_acordo_itau_pf_varejo AS ACORDO

INNER JOIN
DWH_Developer.ASPECT_CONTACT_EVENTS AS LIGACOES ON (LIGACOES.account_number = ACORDO.id_contr)

where ACORDO.DATA>= LIGACOES.time_of_contact 
GROUP BY LIGACOES.ID 
        ,ACORDO.ID_ACORDO
        ,ACORDO.DATA 
        ,LIGACOES.time
```

Comment: Não da certo, pois se incluo o campo LIGACOES.time_of_contact ele não corresponde ao menor fator.

Comment: Para exemplifica, eu selecionei um id de acordo especifico, como você pode ver na imagem. Eu preciso que apareça apenas o registro de menor fator http://i.stack.imgur.com/5LqHg.png

Comment: No meu exemplo é o menor FATOR por ACORDO , para mudar isto bastaria , creio , mudar o agrupamento (GROUP BY).

Comment: Obrigado Motta, mas está dificil! Adicionei mais uma imagem que deve detalhar melhor o problema: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MamHA.png. Será que não consigo ordenar pelo menor fator e depois selecionar sempre o primeiro registro por ID_ACORDO?

Comment: Refiz a Solução , ao meu ver é apenas uma questão de agrupamento , se é que entendi o problema.